# SQL Query returning non-sense results

Tags: php, android, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm experiencing weird behaviour with my database. I've been using the above query where `user` was a variable replaced with a specific user, and it worked perfectly fine. Suddenly, regardless of what I type into `user` I receive the same results where the user is clearly not equal to the one in the query. I first noticed this odd behaviour in my android app, so I looked into the php file and then finally got to the database and discovered the problem occurs here. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check operators precedence in [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

```
SELECT * FORM bet WHERE (user = 'f') AND (status = 'lost' OR status = 'won')
```

Comment: it should not have worked before this change.  possibly there were fewer rows in the database

Comment: There was actually way more, could've sworn there was no issue, very weird